# Calculating the frequency of letters from wordList in java

Tags: java

How can i calculate the frequency of letters from wordList in java .

ALL WORDS ARE STORED IN wordList ARRAYLIST !
     * You need to iterate through each word and 
     * Calculate the frequency of letters in all words in wordList 
     * @return an ArrayList of integers. First element of this is the frequency of a,
     * second element is the frequency of b, and so on.
     * EXAMPLE:
     * if wordList has ["cat","dog","turtle"]
     * freq() --> returned arraylist values: [1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,3,1,0,0,0,0,0]
     * each number in returned arraylist represent how many times each letter appears
     * in wordsList arraylist(a:1,b:0,c:1....so on)
     * */
public ArrayList freq(){

```
    String s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxvz";

       char[] c = s.toCharArray();
       int sz =c.length;
       int  i =0, j=0 , counter=0;

       for( i=0; i<sz; i++) {
           for( j=0; j<sz; ++j) {

        if(c[j] == c[i]) {
            counter++;
        }
       }
return

       }    
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You don't have to shout.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class LetterFrequency 
{
    static final String alphabet    = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    static final char[] alphabetArr = alphabet.toCharArray();
    static final int    NUM_LETTERS = 26;

    public static void main(String argv[]) // test it
    {
        System.out.println("alphbetArr.length = " + alphabetArr.length);
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        words.add("Hello"); words.add("World"); words.add("This"); words.add("Test"); words.add("Works!");
        printResults(getFrequency(words));
    }

    public static int[] getFrequency(ArrayList<String> wordList)
    {
        int[] ret          = new int[NUM_LETTERS];

        for (int i=0; i < wordList.size(); i++)
        {
            String word = wordList.get(i).toLowerCase();
            String len = word.length();
            for (int j=0; j < NUM_LETTERS; j++)
                for(int k=0; k < len; k++)
                    if (alphabetArr[j] == word.charAt(k))
                        ret[j]++
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public static void printResults(int[] freq)
    { for (int i =0; i < freq.length; i++) System.out.print("frequency[" + alphabetArr[i] + "=" + freq[i] + "], "); }
}
```

Comment: ***Produces this result:***
alphbetArr.length = 26
alphbetArr.length = 26
frequency[a=0], frequency[b=0], frequency[c=0], frequency[d=1],
frequency[e=2], frequency[f=0], frequency[g=0], frequency[h=2],
frequency[i=1], frequency[j=0], frequency[k=1], frequency[l=3],
frequency[m=0], frequency[n=0], frequency[o=3], frequency[p=0],
frequency[q=0], frequency[r=2], frequency[s=3], frequency[t=3],
frequency[u=0], frequency[v=0], frequency[w=2], frequency[x=0],
frequency[y=0], frequency[z=0],